# Calculate cp & cpk

Tags: excel, vba

I have recorded a macro to avoid repletion of same task ,
but the first average formula is getting disappeared after execution , please look into the program and kindly help where to correct.
**Actual steps what i want to execute:

1. Average of column c, min of column c, max of column c, average of min & max (all 4 adjacent cells p1,q1,r1,s1)
2. Standard deviation of column c ( cell : p2)
3. 6 * standard deviation (cell : p3)
4. ABS(p1 - s1)/0.31  (cell : p4)
5. 0.62/(p3)   (cell : p5)
6. p5*(1-p4)**

```
    Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(C[-13])"
    Range("Q1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(C[-14])"
    Range("R1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(C[-15])"
    Range("S1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-2]:RC[-1])"
    Range("P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=STDEV(C[-13])"
    Range("P3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=6*R[-1]C"
    Range("P4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-3]C-R[-3]C[3])/0.31"
    Range("P5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=0.62/R[-2]C"
    Range("P6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C*(1-R[-2]C)"
    Range("P5").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the logic of the generated code (i.e. without any optimisation), you need to first select cell P1. In your code the average of column C is entered in the selected cell just before you execute the code.

Try this

```
    Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(C[-13])"
    Range("Q1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MIN(C[-14])"
    Range("R1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(C[-15])"
    Range("S1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(RC[-2]:RC[-1])"
    Range("P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=STDEV(C[-13])"
    Range("P3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=6*R[-1]C"
    Range("P4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(R[-3]C-R[-3]C[3])/0.31"
    Range("P5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=0.62/R[-2]C"
    Range("P6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C*(1-R[-2]C)"
    Range("P5").Select
End Sub
```